# Optional([value])! producing nil (error) despite it having a value

Tags: ios, swift

I have the below code which is optional.

```
"\(postArray[indexPath.row].user.username)"
```

When I print the value I get something like:
    Optional("helloman")
but when I force unwrap to get rid of the Optional() the app crashes 
    nil.
***Why is this happening? How do I fix it?***

I print:

```
    print(postArray[indexPath.row].user.username, " loop full\(indexPath.row)")
    print(postArray[indexPath.row].user.username!, " loop full\(indexPath.row)")
```

And get the following result

```
nil  loop full2
```

//Crash here

I add users to each post Object like this:

```
    func retrieveUsersInfo(userObj: User) {

    let ref = Database.database().reference()

    if userObj.userID != nil {
        print("inside if of retrieveUsers")

        let UID = userObj.userID!
        print(UID, "<-- uid promg")
        let currentUID = "\(UID)"
        print(currentUID, "<<- current uid")
        print(lastUID, "<-- chhhc")

        if lastUID == nil {
            print("last uid 6was nil")
            ref.child("users2").child(UID).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                print(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "username").value as! String, "0302310320101320312032101")

                print("here?")
                do {
                    self.addUserDataToObject(userObj: userObj, snapshot: snapshot)
                }

            })

        } else if currentUID == lastUID! {
            print("hello?")
            ref.child("users2").child(UID).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                print(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "username").value as! String, "0302310320101320312032101")

                do {
                    self.addUserDataToObject(userObj: userObj, snapshot: snapshot)
                }

            })
        } else if currentUID != lastUID! {
            print("vai malandra") //the stuff below should be made into another function to reduce text; be more fficient
            ref.child("users2").child(UID).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                print(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "username").value as! String, "0302310320101320312032101")

                do {
                    self.addUserDataToObject(userObj: userObj, snapshot: snapshot)
                }

            })

        } else {
            print("gggg")
        }
        lastUID = "\(UID)"
    }
}
```

Bellow is func used:

```
    func addUserDataToObject(userObj: User, snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    if "\(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "username").value as! String)" != nil {
        userObj.fullName = "\(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "fullName").value as! String)"
        userObj.username = "\(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "username").value as! String)"
        userObj.profileImageUrl = "\(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "profileImage").value as! String)"
    } else {
        print("the username was nil!")
    }
}
```

For each user that I get from .childAdded which I get from the users following list, I call this method

Comment: Do show the way you are unwrapping and printing the result

Comment: Show how all relevant variables are declared and initialized. Show the exact code that is causing the crash.

Comment: Clearly `username` is `nil` and when you force-unwrap it, it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably at some point an optional value could not have been set. So you should try to use either `guard` or `if let` to make sure you are getting the value when it is set and avoid to crash the app when its nil.